# Find specific value in a column of a list

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to get which objects of a list have an specific value in one of their columns.

In order to explain my case, please run the following simple example:

## mtcars splitted into a list

```
mt_list = split(mtcars, f = mtcars$cyl)
```

## If we take a look into one of the elements, we see column "gear"

```
head(mt_list$`4`)
            
               mpg  cyl  disp hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0 93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7 62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8 95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7 66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7 52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1 65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
```

What I'd like is to know which elements have a value of "4" in the "gear" column. So it will search into all elements of the list , inside the column "gear" and if is found a value of 5 then list the element.

The desired output should be = "4"  "6" , where you can find the value "4" in the column gear. (not present in element "8")

Any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could loop through the `list`, check whether there is `any` element in 'gear' column that is equal to 4, use that to subset the `names` of the `list`

```
names(mt_list)[sapply(mt_list, function(x) any(x$gear == 4))]
#[1] "4" "6"
```

---

Or use `%in%` to create the logical index

```
names(mt_list)[sapply(mt_list, function(x) 4 %in% x$gear)]
#[1] "4" "6"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. One final question, what if instead of the column "Gear" the name is "Car1.Gear" , "Car2.Gear", "Car3.Gear" , etc,etc,etc, so they share the ".Gear" Thanks.

Comment: @Albert In that case change the `x$gear` (anonymous function call or lamba function) to `x[[grep("^Car\\d+\\.Gear$", names(x))]]`